# Write Cache Data Structure in Redis

Tags: npm, redis

Is there any data structure in redis or an NPM package which will hold all incoming data let say for X minutes or until Y item count is reached; post which it should push it to one of the consumers on redis stream?
In total this is a write cache, and my incoming data is list of strings?

Comment: You should be able to implement this with Redis Gears module, for the TTL it is native expiration, for the count you can capture the event in a gears function and delete the value if you have reached the value - take a look to https://redisgears.io/

Comment: I looked at redis gears its not Apache License so cant use it, I was thinking if this can be implemented with lua and core redis .. or if someone has already done this..

Comment: If you cannot use RedisGears, take a look at the Key  Notifications ( https://redis.io/topics/notifications ) this will allow you to capture the event (when the value is updated) and then call some logic (LUA or not) when you reach the threshold is reached. (but you need to be sure the subscriber is up to consume the key notification